# Xlib: window is created in wrong position

Tags: c, xlib

I have simple xlib program which creates window. I think it has to show window on the upper-left corner of the screen because I pass 0, 0 to XCreateSimpleWindow function, but it's in upper-middle side. Why ?

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Display* display;     
  int screen_num;       
  Window win;           
  unsigned int display_width,display_height;    
  unsigned int width, height;   
  char *display_name = getenv("DISPLAY");

  display = XOpenDisplay(display_name);
  screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
  display_width = DisplayWidth(display, screen_num);
  display_height = DisplayHeight(display, screen_num);

  width = (display_width / 3);
  height = (display_height / 3);

  win = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screen_num), 0, 0, width, height, 1, BlackPixel(display, screen_num), WhitePixel(display, screen_num));

  XMapWindow(display, win);

  XSync(display, False);

  while(1) { }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top level windows are placed (and dimensioned) by the window manager which does whatever it suit it. Often the size is respected but the position not (in order to leave place for decoration, in order to respect placement policy of leaving toolbars clear, ...)

Try on a display without a window manager if you want your request to be respected (use VNC or similar to get such a display, don't try to use your desktop like this)

Comment: How to run it on display without window manager? I am using VNC to connect to server.

Comment: Launching a VNC server and then killing the window manager is probably the easiest path. Setting correctly the parameters for the vnc server so that it uses ad hoc start up scripts which don't launch a window manager is probably how things should be done. (For instance passing a special name to vncserver -name and checking for it in VNCDESKTOP in your xstartup).

Comment: I disabled window manager and it works, but without window manager I can't do anything, eg. I can't move or resize  window. Is there any other way without disabling it?

Comment: Deciding where to place the windows is the window manager job. So I'm far from sure that wanting to override it is a good solution. There are case where it is the right thing and IIRC there is some attribute you can place on the window for that, look in the ICCCM.